# Setting selected items in angular-bootstrap-duallistbox, using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With the angular-bootstrap-duallistbox component, documented [here](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-duallistbox), and using the $http service, How do I set the selected elements on it?

Here is the used code:

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in authorizations"
        multiple
        ng-model="selections"
        bs-duallistbox
        ></select>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['frapontillo.bootstrap-duallistbox'])
    .controller('ProfileAutAsigController',
    function ($scope, $http, Authorization) {

    $scope.authorizations = [];
    $scope.selections = [];

    Authorization.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.authorizations = response;
        return $http.get("api/profileAut/1/authorizations");

    }).then(function (payload) {
        //This doesn't set the selected items. Specifying an
        //array manually doesn't work either.
        //$scope.selections = [{id:1, name:'Text'},{id:3, name:'Photos'}];

        $scope.selections = payload.data;

    }, function (payload) {
        //Error happened
        console.log(payload.error);
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you get a response on this one as I have a similar issue

Comment: I didn't get any response, because seems that component fails with $http service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I couldn't make work angular-bootstrap-duallistbox with $http service. I used instead this angular directive, which worked with $http:

https://github.com/alexklibisz/angular-dual-multiselect-directive

Be sure of following the items json format. Read the example.

Answer (score 1):

To populate angular bootstrap dual list box you should use `track by` instead of `as` like this:

You have to use `track by` instead `as` in ng-options

Instead this:

```
 <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="av as av.name for av in available" multiple bs-duallistbox></select>
```

Uses:

```
 <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="av.name for av in available track by av.id" multiple bs-duallistbox></select>
```